# Gradle Kotlin allprojects dependencies cause build failure

Tags: gradle, kotlin

In my Gradle project, I can declare a `dependencies` block with `implementation` entries, no problem. When I try to declare something like this, however, I get an error:

```
allprojects {
    dependencies {
        implementation("...")
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.0]
on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I wasn't able to reproduce this with a Java project, so it might have something to do with the Kotlin project. I'm new to Gradle, so I might just be doing something silly? Here's my environment info:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-02-08 19:00:10 UTC
Revision:     f02764e074c32ee8851a4e1877dd1fea8ffb7183

Kotlin DSL:   1.1.3
Kotlin:       1.3.20
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_112 (Oracle Corporation 25.112-b15)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

---

## Minimal reproduction

I can reproduce the issue with a minimal project.

**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// This works.
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.0'
}

// Causes an error. Using a random dependency to reproduce the issue.
allprojects {
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.0'
    }
}
```

**`settings.gradle:`**

```
rootProject.name = 'demo'

// Removing this line causes the error to go away, but means the module is missing.
include 'submodule'
```

**`submodule/build.gradle`**

```
// Empty file. I've tried adding various plugins (java / kotlin) to no avail.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your `build.gradle` is you are trying to use a build dependency configuration, in this case `implementation` without specifying the `java` plugin. The gradle docs says;

> The Java plugin adds a number of dependency configurations to your
>   project, as shown below. Tasks such as compileJava and test then use
>   one or more of those configurations to get the corresponding files and
>   use them, for example by placing them on a compilation or runtime
>   classpath.

One way to fix this is to include `java` plugin as below (I have tested on 5.2.1 and it worked fine);

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.25.0'
    }
}
```

The relationship of build configuration to the `java` plugin has been comprehensively described on 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management

and

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_dependency_configurations.html#managing_dependency_configurations

Also, make sure you don't duplicate this dependency (or any other which is declared in the root or for all projects) in subprojects.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!

I'm using the Kotlin DSL in my project (but wanted to make my reproduction as minimal as possible). This worked nicely for me with Kotlin:

allprojects {
  apply<JavaPlugin>())
  dependencies { ... }
}

Comment: Also noteworthy, I already had the java plugin enabled in my submodule, but I guess the `allprojects {}` block is executed before the submodule's `plugins {}` block.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped. Yes, root module where you have allProjects gets picked first. Look for gradle multi module projects on google, there’s a good doc.